# VBA: How to hide filtered (Spliced) Columns?

Tags: vba, excel, filter, slicers

I'm trying to implement a VBA code that hides columns that are "Unnecessary" for the chosen filter.

I am using Slicers to ease up filtering for my table but each subset has different information (data entries) in them.

Eg. Filtering for type A have data in columns E & F, while type B has data in E and G etc.

Now I wish to, at any given moment, only show columns that have data in them, to make the dataset more user-friendly.

I am currently working on this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    n = Rows(2).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    For c = 3 To n
        Cells(3, c).EntireColumn.Hidden = (Application.CountA(Columns(c)) < 2)
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As you may notice, this does not hide columns based on the "Active filter" from the slicer, nor does it trigger on changing the filter (eg choosing type B rather than Type A in the slicer)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub hideempty()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastrow as long
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'If it has a fixed number of columns, _
                                                        you can replace this to LastCol = 5, for example. _
                                                        The number 1 is the row where the headers are
For i = 1 To LastCol
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrow <= 1 Then '1 considering every column has a header, regardless of having any data. _
                            If there are no headers, replace with 0
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else 'this will show columns that were previously hidden if now they have data
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work! However, I am still struggling with continuous update on slicer-selection. E.g. opening up some, and hiding some columns depending on the selection chosen in the slicer!

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question. I totally blanked out on the slicer thing. I'll see if I can do it better

Comment: Thank you, i can't seem to find any way to trigger/execute code via slicers, especially not when implemented on a regular table, not on a pivottable.